# Javascript read gz files from node/express server

Tags: json, node.js, express, gzip

A .NET service export *.gz files to a nodejs server. The files are gziped json strings.

This is the node route for saving the files locally.

```
router.post("/", function (req, res) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../public", "data", req.header("filename"));
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    req.pipe(writeStream);
    req.on("end", function () {
        writeStream.close();
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

Now I have .gz files in my public/data directory.

I request a file from a client side js like that:

```
static fetchJsonFile(path:string, callback:Function):void {
    let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                let data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.response);
                if (callback)
                    callback("OK", data);
            }
            else if (httpRequest.status === 404) {
                if (callback)
                    callback("Resource not found", null);
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open("GET", path, true);
    httpRequest.responseType = "json";
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

It doesn't work - returns httpRequest.response == null. However the server log shows that the file is served: `GET /data/EURUSD1440.gz 200 1.352 ms - 322044`
**EDIT** When I set the `httpRequest.responseType` equal to `"text"`, the  `httpRequest.response` receives the file compressed and cannot be parsed.

How to make the client reading, decompressing and parsing the gzipped files?

I tried many variant bit no success. Some of my tries:

With Connect and connect-gzip-static:

```
connect().use(gzipStatic(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

With `fs` in `routes/data.js`:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../public", "data", req.header("filename"));
    console.log(filePath);

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    res.setHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","gzip");

    readStream.on("open", function () {
        readStream.pipe(res);
    });

    readStream.on("end", function() {
        readStream.close();
        console.log("there will be no more data.");
    });

    readStream.on("error", function(err) {
        res.end(err);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I have no success. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It looks like I cannot set the response header correctly to sate that the content is gzipped. My server main loop looks  like that:

```
"use strict";

var debug = require("debug")("Ea_Studio:server");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("serve-favicon");
var logger = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var fs = require("fs");
var routes = require("./routes/index");
var data = require("./routes/data");

var app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico")));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");


app.use("/", routes);
app.use("/data", data);
```

It looks like the get request is not managed by the `routes/data.js`

Comment: If the file is in `public` then the `express.static` middleware handles it because it comes first.

Comment: I see that but I was not able to resolve in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it by using the `serve-static` module. It allows me to set `gzip` headers for the `public/data` route.

```
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/public/data", {setHeaders: setDataFilesHeaders}));
function setDataFilesHeaders(res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "gzip");
}

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/public"));
```